# 2nd Smallest value based on criteria

Tags: excel

Aim: I have all distinct names (in this case column K) and want to search down my list, column D. When I find D and K match I want to find the 2nd smallest value in E and show this value.

Code so far: `=VLOOKUP(SMALL(E:E,2),D:D,1,K4)`

Closest, but without Small filter `=VLOOKUP($K5,$D$2:$E$999,2,FALSE)`

Errors is #Value (and I can see there are actual values)

Also tried: `=VLOOKUP(IF($D:$D=$K5,SMALL($E:$E,1),"X"),D:E,2)` - does not filter criteia

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Aggregate:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,$D$2:$D$9/($C$2:$C$9=$F4),2)
```

The `2` at the end tells the function to return the second smallest.  Change that to 1 for the first.

The columns are based on your data in the screen shot.  It assumes that the first column is A and the first row is 1.